# giving mysql error when using value with '

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have written a query

```
mysql_query("insert into db_manufacturer(mfgName) values('$manufacturer')"
```

when `$manufacturer = ram's` or `sam's` etc then it is giving `sql` error, how to overcome this error. If I am using `""` then in the db inserting the variable not the variable value.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, 
[here is a good tutorial](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14110189/1723893).

Answer (score 2):

```
 mysql_query("insert into db_manufacturer(mfgName) values('$manufacturer')")
```

and  when `$manufacturer` is `"ram's"` it will be like

```
 mysql_query("insert into db_manufacturer(mfgName) values('ram's')")
```

This is broken as the value closing delimiter appears twice; that is, there are an odd number of single quotemarks.

**now solution**

```
mysql_query("
  INSERT INTO db_manufacturer
    (mfgName)
  VALUES
    ('".mysql_real_escape_string($manufacturer)."')
");
```

A good, easy, scalable and safe approach is to use parameterized queries. The parameters for such queries are called bind variables.

**Good Read**

1. [How to prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)
2. [**Are PDO prepared statements sufficient to prevent SQL injection?**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12202218/1723893)

---

### **Note**

1. The entire **`ext/mysql`** PHP extension, which provides all functions named with the prefix mysql_, is [officially deprecated as of PHP v5.5.0](http://php.net/manual/en/changelog.mysql.php) and will be removed in the future. So use either `PDO` or `MySQLi`

**Good read**

1. [The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13944956/the-mysql-extension-is-deprecated-and-will-be-removed-in-the-future-use-mysqli/13944958#comment19236631_13944958.)
2. [PDO Tutorial for MySQL Developers](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers)
3. [Pdo Tutorial For Beginners](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php/14110189#14110189)

Answer (score 1):

```
$manufacturer = mysql_real_escape_string($manufacturer);
mysql_query("insert into db_manufacturer(mfgName) values('$manufacturer')";
```

Comment: forget mysql_.Use mysqli_ or PDO

Comment: That does not warrant a downvote. It perfectly "answers" what was being asked. We can "recommend" someone to use mysqli or PDO but we cannot force them to change their solution just based upon a question, imo.

Comment: is it really good to use singleton ?

Answer (score 1):

```
$manufacturer = mysql_real_escape_string($manufacturer);
mysql_query("insert into db_manufacturer(mfgName) values('$manufacturer')"
```

- [mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php)

but i Recommend to use either PDO or MySQLI.

Here's a great article:

- [How to prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: forget mysql_.Use mysqli_ or PDO

Comment: @AnazA did you read what's written below?

Comment: may i ask why use singleton ?

Answer (score 0):

Use `mysql_real_escape_string` which escapes special characters in a string for use in an SQL statement

```
$manufacturer = mysql_real_escape_string($manufacturer);
```

More details:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php

Comment: forget mysql_.Use mysqli_ or PDO

Comment: @AnazA : Is this comment for me?

Answer (score 0):

It is deprecated but you are looking for `mysql_real_escape_string`.

but forget `mysql_` and learn PDO, it is much safer.